# How do I hide one menu item link for logged in and logged out users

Tags: menus, user-access

Using bbPress and s2Member, I need to hide the registration link in the menu for logged in users and the members directory link for non logged in users.

Answer (score 3):

A simple way to achieve that is to create two separate [Navigation Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Navigation_Menus) (`/wp-admin/nav-menus.php`), and in your theme use the following:

```
// Reference:
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in
// http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_nav_menu

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'logged-users' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'not-logged-users' ) );
}
```

Instead of `theme_location`, you can use the menu name directly, check the documentation for `wp_nav_menu`.
And you'd probably would like to use the function `is_user_logged_in` in the template files for the Registration and Directory pages.

Comment: Thanks but no template files for the registration and template file. Can i use this code in the child themes functions.php? I'm using a Genesis child theme. i guess i can use the primary and secondary menu's in the same location?

Comment: <code>add_action( 'genesis_after_header', 'genesis_do_nav' );
function genesis_do_nav () {

if( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'logged-in' => 'logged-users' ) );
} else {
    wp_nav_menu( array( 'logged-out' => 'not-logged-users' ) );
},</code>